# SQL Server 2012 Table Columns & Performance

Tags: sql-server, database-design, tablecolumn

I currently have a web site hitting 7 Access DBs that I desperately need to move to SQL Server. The 7 db design is screaming fast, but obviously very poor for a number of reasons.

In the 7 dbs I have collectively over 375 unique fields of data virtually all of which are populated - less than 2% are nulls. Short of a few keys, there is no duplication of data across the 7 so normalization is probably not an issue. I wanted to keep the tables small so it would be fast. The 7 tables all have the identical number of records which is 325,000 and will max out around 400,000.

When moving this to SQL Server should I keep the 7 unique tables or combine into 1? My understanding (limited as it is) was that I would need to be very disciplined in my stored procedures to only bring back the columns I need. Given the huge variety of similar questions I still never came across a "consensus" on the best approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the schema of each of the 7 tables the same?

Comment: "I wanted to keep the tables small so it would be fast." Uh?

Comment: Not sure how to answer the schema question. The data is bank data, so one db contains Balance Sheet, another Loan data, another Income Statement and so on. All the data is tied together by a unique bank id. No duplication and not many nulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your access patterns. Do you often need to access data from multiple partitions at once? Then you should probably combine them.

Anyway, development is probably easier when you only have one table (without one-to-one joins). If there is no particular reason to split them, combine them.

Attention: I think there is a column limit in SQL Server.

You can expose subsets of the columns by creating indexes. Each index would be set on the ID column with an arbitrary subset of columns as "included" columns. **This will leave the choice to the optimizer.** It will choose the best possible way. It can also join between indexes so you are in a total win situation that way.

Recommendation: Combine the tables into one and create one index for each table you previously had.

Comment: Thanks USR, I appreciate your time. I believe you are correct on the limit (1024). My primary concern is not ease of development, but rather speed of Stored Procedures in bringing data back.

Comment: Ok, starting from that goal your decision depends on your access patterns.

Comment: I realize this will sound completely naive, but what does "Access Patterns" mean? I will be hitting the table with 70+ stored procedures touching all the different columns (fields). One SP may hit columns A & B & C while another will hit D & E.

Comment: Access pattern = the reads and writes you are doing. I gather that you are mostly using multiple tables in the same query. This means you need to join which is very slow compared to having larger rows. It seems to me that you are much better off combining the tables to get rid of the joins. Btw, you can expose subsets of the columns by creating indexes. Each index would be set on the ID column with an arbitrary subset of columns as "included" columns. This will leave the choice to the optimizer.

Comment: I added a little text to the answer. Why didn't I think of that before?